# Find the distance using longitude and latitude between a row in df1 and run it against all rows in df2, then display the minimum distance

Tags: python, distance

I have two dataframes df1 contains longitude and latitude of all hospitals and df2 contains longitude and latitude of cities. I want to find the distance of each of the hospitals between all of the cities to determine which one is the nearest hospital to the city.

sample values

```
 df1
 hos   lng   lat
 hos1   2     3
 hos2   1     4
 hos3   2     1

 df2
 city  lng   lat
 cit1   5     3
 cit2   6     3
 cit3   2     1


 for i in df1:
 #get the distance of all cities with each hospital
 #get distance between two lon and lat

     def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
         p = 0.017453292519943295
         a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2
         return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))

     def closest(data, city):
     return min(data, key=lambda p:distance(city['lat'],city['lon'],p['lat'],p['lon']))
```

its not displaying anything. Should I use nested loops for this case? How do I print all of the distances of all hospitals and cities as well?

something like:

```
      hos1  hos2  hos3
 cit1  x     x      x
 cit2  x     x      x
 cit3  x     x      x
```

Comment: You only defined the functions but didn't call them

Answer (score 0):

A good way to achieve this kind of process is to use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html) for each city.

Example:

```
# Priorize
priorities = {}
for city in cities:
    priorities[city] = []
    for hospital in hospitals:
        heappush(priorities[city], (distance(city, hospital), hospital))

# Get the closest hospital for a city
closest = heappop(priorities[your_city])[1]
```

> NB: You define methods that you never call, and you do not store your data in a structure, that's why you don't get anything...